# how to call ngDialog.open in unit tests using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using Jasmine/Karma for unit testing and new to these frameworks.In contrller i am using ngDialog for model displaying and i want unit test cases for controller calling ngDialog.
**Controller:**

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app')
      .controller('myController', MyController);

    CongratulationsController.$inject = ['$scope',
                                         '$rootScope',
                                         'ngDialog'];

    function CongratulationsController($scope, $rootScope, ngDialog) {

      $scope.myData = {name: 'test',
                      grade: '5'};

      $scope.modal1 = function() {
        ngDialog.open({ template: 'views/modal/modal-1html',
          className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
          controller: 'ModalController',
          scope: $scope});
      };
      $scope.modal2 = function() {
        ngDialog.open({ template: 'views/modal/modal-2html',
          className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
          controller: 'ModalController',
          scope: $scope});
      };
    }
}());
```

Here is my **Unit test** :

```js
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MyController', function () {
  var MyController,location, scope, ngDialogInstance;
  ngDialogInstance = {
    open: jasmine.createSpy('ngDialogInstance.open'),
    dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.dismiss')
  };
    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('app'));
    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $location, $rootScope, _ngDialog_) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MyController= $controller('myController', {$scope: scope ,
          _ngDialog_: ngDialogInstance
          });
        location = $location;
        spyOn(scope, 'openModal1');
    }));
    it('test controller exists', function () {
        expect(!!MyController).toBe(true);
    });
    
  it('test controller calls ng dialog when it calls openModel method', function () {
    scope.openModal1();
    expect(scope.openModal1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ngDialogInstance.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

when i am running aboove test case, getting below error.
its failing at  **Expected spy ngDialogInstance.open to have been called.**

can any one help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

This should be,

```
it('test controller calls ng dialog when it calls openModel method', function () {
    ngDialogInstance.open();
    scope.openModal1();
    expect(scope.openModal1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ngDialogInstance.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

You have to include below line:

```
ngDialogInstance.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to mock `ngDialogInstance.open` method. So change your this part of code

`it('test controller calls ng dialog when it calls openModel method', function () {
    scope.openModal1();
    expect(scope.openModal1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ngDialogInstance.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });`

into this

`it('test controller calls ng dialog when it calls openModel method', function () {
    spyOn(ngDialogInstance, 'open');
    scope.openModal1();
    expect(scope.openModal1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ngDialogInstance.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });`

Note: spyOn spy the method which you are going to test,  it spy that it has been called or not, has been called with correct parameters or not etc.

for more info on spyOn go tho official doc of [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are wondering as to why the open function has to be called like

```
ngDialogInstance.open();
```

, it is because you need to mimic a user's interaction with the dialog such as close , open etc.